# Debugging Xcode project with framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, frameworks

currently we've build an app including a pairing library. 
this works perfect when we use the simulator or connect an iphone/ipad to test the app.
at the moment we're ready to upload it to the appstore and there's suddenly an error:
this is the message:

[image: Xcode Error Image]

Comment: What XCode version do you use? Is your library version up to date?

Comment: I'm using Xcode 8.3.2. I'm using the RemObjectsSDK framework. I updated the framework because there was a update but I've got the same error

Answer (score 1):

You should add a run script phase that removes the x86_64 architecture from your library (after all, it is only there for simulator runs and isn't needed for AppStore distribution). Use the solution described here: http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/

Comment: The value from valid architectures is now: arm64 armv7. But it doesn't remove the error. Maybe it's bitcode? It's a 3th party framework do I need to set yes or no at enable bitcode under build options?

Comment: If you enable bitcode in your project, but the 3rd party doesn't have bitcode, it SHOULD create a problem. However, as far as I remember, the linker error in that case would have had the word "bitcode" in its description. Sorry that I don't have any farther ideas...